# Installing Features On Demand from an ISO File

Tags: windows-10-v1809

I am trying to install RSAT tools on Windows 10 1809 through Features on Demand since that is where they put them now instead of downloading a package installed. (Because why make it easy). I have imported cab file:

```
Microsoft-Windows-Server-AppCompat-FoD-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab
```

So when I do `/Get-Capabilities` it shows I have the RSAT tools available but not present.

So I do the following

```
DISM.exe /online /add-capability /capabilityname:Rsat.Dns.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0
```

I get this error:

```
Error: 0x800f0954 
DISM failed. No operation was performed.
For more information review the log file.
```

When I check the log file I see this Warning:

```
Failed to load the provider: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\<random number>\EmbeddedProvider.dll. - CDISMProvider Store::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e)
```

And then Error

```
Failed finalizing changes . - CDISMPackagemanager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x800f0954)
```

Any ideas why I can't install these features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this notes on Microsoft [Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=45520)

> Known issues affecting various RSAT versions:
>
> Issue: RSAT FOD installation fails with error code 0x800f0954
> Impact: RSAT FODs on Windows 10 1809 (October 2018 Update) in WSUS/SCCM environments
> Resolution: To install FODs on a domain-joined PC which receives updates through WSUS or SCCM, you will need to change a Group Policy setting to enable downloading FODs directly from Windows Update or a local share.

Just create special share on local network for **Feature On Demand** (FOD) sources and configure **Group Policy** option for using this share. Like [here](https://blog.it-kb.ru/2019/05/31/offline-install-rsat-remote-server-administration-tools-from-feature-on-demand-sources-in-fod-share-for-windows-10-1903/)

Or you can try direct installation from a source using **PowerShell**:

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Online| ?{$_.name -like '*RSAT*'} | Add-WindowsCapability -Online -LimitAccess -Source "\\Path\to\FOD-Sources-ISO\"
```